# C# IOException Cannot locate resource

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a C# project where I have some PNG files in a *Images* directory.

The structure of the project can be simplified to:

```
|
ViewModel.cs
View.xaml
|
[Images]
    \
    MapImageLayer16.png
```

In my view I bind to an object containing a string property *ImagePath*, pointing to `../Images/MapImageLayer16.png`, and another string property *Name*:

```
<ListBox x:Name="DataLayerList" ItemsSource="{Binding LayersFiltered, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}" Height="16"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Now, the name comes trough fine. However, the image fails with the following description:

*Failed to convert value '/Images/MapImageLayer16.png' (type 'String') to the target type using converter 'TargetDefaultValueConverter'. The fallback value will be used if it's available. IOException:'System.IO.IOException: Cannot locate resource 'images/mapimagelayer16.png'.*

I tried all sorts of things by now:

- changed the string value to ../Images/MapImageLayer16.png
- changed the string value to pack://application:,,,/Images/MapImageLayer16.png
- switched from string to Uri

Nothing works! How can I get the PNGs to show?

Comment: have you try Images/MapImageLayer16.png without the initial '/'?

Comment: Yes, I did. The issue is still the same.
I also checked if the Images folder is actually created in the bin/debug folder, since I defined the images as embedded resources. The folder is created and filled with the images.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a typical WPF resource error to me. Open the {projectname}.csproj file and add this (adjust if necessary if the structure is not correct)

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\MapImageLayer16.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

> Not in "PropertyGroup" but in "Project" as it can be seen here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a common error when we forget to set the properties of the image as a Resource (on VisualStudio, Rightclic on the image > Properties > Build Action : Resource & Copy to OutputDirectory : Do not copy)
2. You also need to bind a BitmapImage, and not a string, to the Xaml Image control. In your CS code, the ImagePath must become :

   ```
   public BitmapImage Source => new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImagePath, UriKind.Relative));
   ```

with ImagePath = "/Images/MapImageLayer16.png"